# Keras the simplest NN model: error in training.py with indices

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, mnist

I have read this example https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py and decide to use this idea to my base because this is the simplest NN for Keras.

This is my base https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-B3QUQOzGZ7WVhzQmRsOTB0eFE/view
(you can download my csv file, it's only 83Kb )

This is picture my base:
[image]

base.shape = (891, 23)

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop, Adam
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from keras.utils.vis_utils import model_to_dot
from IPython.display import SVG
from keras.utils import plot_model

base = pd.read_csv("mt.csv")

import pandas as pd

for col in base:
    if col != "Fare" and col != "Age":
    base[col]=base[col].astype(float)
X_train = base
y_train = base["Survived"]
del X_train["Survived"]

print("X_train=",X_train.shape)
print("y_train=", y_train.shape)
```

Out:
X_train= (891, 22)
y_train= (891,)

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

X_train, X_test , y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

batch_size = 4
num_classes = 2
epochs = 2

print(X_train.shape[1], 'train samples')
print(X_test.shape[1], 'test samples')
```

Out:
22 train samples
22 test samples

```
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(40, activation='relu', input_shape=(21,)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
#model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
#odel.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()
```

Out:

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param

dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 40)                880

---

dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 40)                0

---

dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 82

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer=Adam(),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

plot_model(model, to_file='model.png')

SVG(model_to_dot(model).create(prog='dot', format='svg'))

print("X_train.shape=", X_train.shape)
print("X_test=",X_test.shape)

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                batch_size=batch_size,
                epochs=epochs,
                verbose=1,
                validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 67, in 
    validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

File "miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 845, in fit
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)

File "miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1405, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)

File "miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1295, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='model input')

File "miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 133, in _standardize_input_data
    str(array.shape))

ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (None, 21) but got array with shape (623, 22)
[Finished in 5.1s with exit code 1]

**How can I solve this error? I tried to change input shape, for example, to (20,) or to (22,), etc. Without success.**

For example, if input_shape=(22,) I have the error: File "miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1873, in maybe_convert_indices
    raise IndexError("indices are out-of-bounds")

Comment: Could you print shape of `y_test`?

Comment: y_train.shape (623, 2)
y_test.shape (268, 2)

Comment: And `X_test` shape?

Comment: X_test.shape (268, 22)
X_train.shape (623, 22)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`input_shape` should be same as the number of features in your data and that should be `input_shape=(22,)` in your case.

The `IndexError` is due to some different indexing in pandas dataframe, so convert your dataframe into a numpy matrix using `as_matrix()`:

```
history = model.fit(X_train.as_matrix(), y_train,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            epochs=epochs,
            verbose=1,
            validation_data=(X_test.as_matrix(), y_test))
```