# ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. in training section

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

## value Error

I have 5722 pictures for training and when I process it is showing error: ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 5722 input samples and 312 target samples.

- 5722 images belonging to 12 classes in training set.
- 312 images belonging to 12 classes in validation set.

```
start = datetime.datetime.now()
model = Sequential() 
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=train_data.shape[1:])) 
model.add(Dense(100, activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3))) 
model.add(Dropout(0.5)) 
model.add(Dense(50, activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3))) 
model.add(Dropout(0.3)) 
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
   optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
   metrics=['acc'])
history = model.fit(train_data, train_labels, 
   epochs=7,
   batch_size=batch_size, 
   validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))
model.save_weights(top_model_weights_path)
(eval_loss, eval_accuracy) = model.evaluate( 
    validation_data, validation_labels, batch_size=batch_size,     verbose=1)
```

## Value Error

### Found 5722 input samples and 312 target samples.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/activations.py:235: UserWarning: Do not pass a layer instance (such as LeakyReLU) as the activation argument of another layer. Instead, advanced activation layers should be used just like any other layer in a model.
      identifier=identifier.__class__.__name__))
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-22-9fbdd01293a7> in <module>()
         13    epochs=7,
         14    batch_size=batch_size,
    ---> 15    validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))
         16 model.save_weights(top_model_weights_path)
         17 (eval_loss, eval_accuracy) = model.evaluate( 
    
    2 frames
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in check_array_length_consistency(inputs, targets, weights)
        242                          'the same number of samples as target arrays. '
        243                          'Found ' + str(list(set_x)[0]) + ' input samples '
    --> 244                          'and ' + str(list(set_y)[0]) + ' target samples.')
        245     if len(set_w) > 1:
        246         raise ValueError('All sample_weight arrays should have '
    
    ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 5722 input samples and 312 target samples.
```

Comment: Can you show how you load your validation data? Or at least the output of `np.shape(validation_data)`, `np.shape(validation_labels)`

Comment: that text data and validation data were imported and pre-trained  by VGG16 validation label contain class names

Comment: It's hard to tell without more details, but it would seem that you have mixed training and validation data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem. It is the length of the inputs must be identical. So, I modify the input data to the same length, as well as the output.

For example, I set the length of both input to 12 by pre-processing the data.

[Example Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293832/keras-the-simplest-nn-model-error-in-training-py-with-indices?rq=1)

```
 history = model.fit(X_train.as_matrix(), y_train,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        epochs=epochs,
        verbose=1,
        validation_data=(X_test.as_matrix(), y_test))
```